# The XAP file not exist in Temporary Internet Files

Tags: silverlight

When the Silverlight application is loaded , I expect that Xap file should be in Temporary Internet Files, but can not find it, how can I make sure that my default path and do I have any setting to change this path and is it possible to run silverlight application without Xap file. I mean the Framework loads the Xap file in memory and stores the Xap file in Temporary Internet Files for future use ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For in-browser applications the plugin relies on the browser's cache ("temporary internet files" in the case of internet explorer). For out-of-browser applications the xap will be stored in a file called application.xap in .../AppData/Local/Microsoft/Silverlight/OutOfBrowser/. or similar.

I'm not sure why you couldn't find it in IE's cache. I clearly see xaps cached in Chrome which is what I mostly use.

Comment: Hi John, Thank you for your answer, in development environment I can find the Xap file in Temporary folder but in production environment can not.